# What is the point of overriding the getInsets() method?

Tags: java, swing

I'm looking at the documentation for `javax.swing.JComponent`, and this method stuck out to me because I am currently trying to create a subclass of this type. Is there any point in overriding the `getInsets()`? What is the purpose of this method when we already have `getPreferredSize()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getInsets` defines space which can be taken up by extra content, like borders, which is, generally, added to the `preferredSize` and offsets the position (translates) of the `Graphics` context, to ensure that the actual content is painted instead the `insets`.

Personally, unless you intend to prevent anybody from modifying the state of the components borders or are thinking for providing margins of some sort, I'd leave it alone (and not override it)